# Cast factor to a character vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, casting

I am learning R at the moment and have a question regarding when I have a factor with a limited number of entries.

I want to cast "Nationality" to a character vector, to allow me to add in several entries, and then to cast it back to a factor as before.
Code as below:

```
name <- c("Amy", "Bill", "Carl")
class(name)

DAD <- c(80, 65, 50)
BDA <- c(70, 50, 80.4)

gender <- as.factor(c("F", "M", "M"))
nationality <- as.factor(c("IRL", "UK", "IRL"))
age <- c(20, 21, 22)

age <- as.integer(age)
DAD <- as.integer(DAD)
BDA <- as.integer(BDA)
student <- data.frame(name, age, gender, nationality, DAD, BDA)

student$average <- as.double(as.double(student$BDA) + as.double(student$DAD))/2

#Want to break the restrictions on nationality below: 
nationality <- data.frame(lapply(nationality, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#Want to add these students: 
student <- rbind(student, c("Aennis", 23, "M", "FR", 55, 75, NA))
student <- rbind(student, c("Cennis", 23, "M", "SP", 55, 45, NA))

#Want to cast it back to a factor after it.
```

I know I could just add "FR" and "SP" to my factor and that's job done, and that I should use a list in any case, but I'm really just playing around with R and trying to learn the syntax of the language and how to do what I want to do, to try understand how it all works, rather than just learning the solution!

Comment: If you add rows using `rbind` and a vector like `c("Aennis", 23, "M", "FR", 55, 75, NA)` it's going to turn all your variables into character vectors because `c("Aennis", 23, "M", "FR", 55, 75, NA)` is a character vector (the numbers are automatically coerced). That means you'll need to convert your variables back into integers, doubles, etc. after each row is added. You would be better off `rbind`ing with a data frame, e.g. `rbind(student, \`colnames<-\`(data.frame("Aennis", 23, "M", "FR", 55, 75, NA), names(student)))`.

Comment: I am stumbling a bit over your code. There is a problem with making the student df as you have only 2 nationalities, but all the other rows you bring in have 3 row. It also does not make sense to put all the *as.double* in, when making *student$average* as the result will be cast into numeric anyhow.

Comment: Yes apologies - updated now

Comment: Why the nationality df? It is not used anywhere.

Comment: MarBlo that's the question! It is a factor originally, I want to break it out so I can add all these other countries, and then re-set it as a factor.

Comment: You don't have to do this. With the 2 solutions below you get it all for free.

Answer (score 0):

i made you this forloop to change factors into character, i hope it helps your understanding of transforming factors.

```
for (col in colnames(student)) {
  if(class(student[,col])=="factor"){
    student[,col] <- as.character(levels(student[,col])[student[,col]])
  }
}
```

then you can append the extra students

Full Code:

```
name <- c("Amy", "Bill", "Carl")
class(name)

DAD <- c(80, 65, 50)
BDA <- c(70, 50, 80.4)

gender <- as.factor(c("F", "M", "M"))

#added an extra "UK"
nationality <- as.factor(c("IRL", "UK", "UK"))
age <- c(20, 21, 22)

age <- as.integer(age)
DAD <- as.integer(DAD)
BDA <- as.integer(BDA)


student <- data.frame(name, age, gender, nationality, DAD, BDA)
student$average <-  as.double(as.double(student$BDA) + as.double(student$DAD))/2

for (col in colnames(student)) {
  if(class(student[,col])=="factor"){
    student[,col] <- as.character(levels(student[,col])[student[,col]])
  }
}


#now you can add your students
student <- rbind(student, c("Aennis", 23, "M", "FR", 55, 75, NA))
student <- rbind(student, c("Cennis", 23, "M", "SP", 55, 45, NA))

#run avarage again
student$average <-  as.double(as.double(student$BDA) + as.double(student$DAD))/2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach takes your edited post, but neglects the nationality df. The calculation of *student$average* casts the result into *numeric* without using *as.double*.

I have added the base-R version of @gersht. This is the most succinct solution and he should get the credit for this.

I have also added a tidyverse-solution, just because this would be my favorite way.

```r
name <- c("Amy", "Bill", "Carl")
class(name)
#> [1] "character"

DAD <- c(80, 65, 50)
BDA <- c(70, 50, 80.4)

gender <- as.factor(c("F", "M", "M"))
nationality <- as.factor(c("IRL", "UK", "IRL"))
age <- c(20, 21, 22)

age <- as.integer(age)
DAD <- as.integer(DAD)
BDA <- as.integer(BDA)

student <- data.frame(name, age, gender, nationality, DAD, BDA)

student$average <- (student$BDA + student$DAD) / 2

# the rbind-way ==> base-R. credit to @gersht
student <- rbind(
  student,
  `colnames<-`(data.frame("Aennis", 23, "M", "FR", 55, 75, NA), names(student))
)

student
#>     name age gender nationality DAD BDA average
#> 1    Amy  20      F         IRL  80  70    75.0
#> 2   Bill  21      M          UK  65  50    57.5
#> 3   Carl  22      M         IRL  50  80    65.0
#> 4 Aennis  23      M          FR  55  75      NA

# the tidyverse-way
library(tidyverse)
student <- student %>%
  mutate(nationality = as.character(nationality)) %>%
  add_row(
    name = "George", gender = "M", age = "44",
    nationality = "NL", BDA = 0, DAD = 5
  ) %>%
  mutate(nationality = as.factor(nationality))

student
#>     name age gender nationality DAD BDA average
#> 1    Amy  20      F         IRL  80  70    75.0
#> 2   Bill  21      M          UK  65  50    57.5
#> 3   Carl  22      M         IRL  50  80    65.0
#> 4 Aennis  23      M          FR  55  75      NA
#> 5 George  44      M          NL   5   0      NA

levels(student$nationality)
#> [1] "FR"  "IRL" "NL"  "UK"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>